# What does GT stand for as in GT1, GTX graphics core nomenclatures?

Tags: graphics-card, terminology

Does GT stand for anything? If not, does anyone know the historical context/origination of this?

Some say, it stands for GigaTransfers. But I don't think GT1 means 1 Giga Transfers and surely GTX will not add up to any number. Also am I right in thinking that GT on Intel graphics card could mean different than GT name on Nvidia one?

Comment: Intel "GT" means "Graphics Technology".

Comment: If it stands for something, and Nvidia has not specifically indicated what it means, then you can assume it just product branding.  The only two product brands you mention are GT and GTX by the way.  GT is a lower price point brand then GTX.

Comment: [If you want to know what the Nvidia brands are check the GeForce Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce)

Answer (score 0):

In consumer product names (for example 'GeForce GTX 1080'), it's just branding.  For Intel's hardware designations, it refers to the particular GPU core (just like the R numbers for older ATI/AMD cards, and the letter plus number codes for NVIDIA cards).

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Intel processor graphics, it means **Graphics Technology**. [The official collective name for Intel's on-chip graphics solutions is "**Intel Graphics Technology**"](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/visual-technology/graphics-overview.html), which encompasses HD Graphics, UHD Graphics, and Iris Graphics.

For NVIDIA GeForce cards, it's simply a brand name. GT is used to refer to entry-level graphics solutions below those branded "GTX"; graphics processors with GT branding, like the GeForce GT 1030, are meant for basic applications. While they are generally faster than Intel processor graphics solutions, they are not well-suited for gaming or other graphically-intensive applications.

Answer (score -1):

Although not directly related, this is speculative, Nvidia used GTS as the naming of one one of their earlier Geforce cards, the Geforce 2 GTS, where it meant "Giga Texel Shader".
It was cards with shaders that could render more than 1 Giga Texels, hence GT!
The "GT" back then meant "Giga Texels".
https://www.anandtech.com/show/537
(a classic Anandtech review from as early as 2000).
It was the first serious Geforce card that really took a leap in performance compared to the competitors. The former cards had problems with memory speed (not having DDR memory available among other things).
That usage of GT somehow carried on with an added "X" for "GTX" in later series cards and nowadays it is probably just used by default.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).